# Adding Custom Header to List Fragment in Android

Tags: java, android, header, adapter, android-listfragment

I am trying to add a custom header that isnt clickable but will have a checkbox that will "check all" checkboxes under it.

This is my List Fragment

```
public class AssesmentListFragment extends ListFragment {

private static String BUNDLE_KEY_APPLICATION = "LIST_ITEM";
FastAssesmentListAdapter adapter;
View listHeader;

public AssesmentListFragment() {}

public AssesmentListFragment(Data[] data) {

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     

    Data[] assestments = {new Data("Assesment ID","Name", "Date"), new Data("123456", "Assestment 2", "9/12/12"),
            new Data("345672", "Assesment 3", "9/13/12"), new Data("566893", "Assesment 4", "9/14/12")};

            //This is the part that makes the app crash
    View header = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_adapter_assesments, null);
    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.addHeaderView(header);

    adapter = new FastAssesmentListAdapter(getActivity(), assestments);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    updateList(assestments);
}



@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

}
private void updateList(Data[] assestments) {
    // NOTE: addAll is not being used to support pre-honeycomb devices

    synchronized(adapter) {
        adapter.clear();
        adapter.addAll(assestments);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
    String model = (String) parentView.getItemAtPosition(position);
    ((FacilityActivity) getActivity()).onItemSelected(model);

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    //outState.putInt("curChoice", mCurCheckPosition);
  } 
 }
```

This is the layout I am trying to use for header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="25dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"> 

<TextView android:id="@+id/adapter_header_textview_column1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:textColor="@color/defaultTextColor"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:text="Assesment ID" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/adapter_header_textview_column2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:textColor="@color/defaultTextColor"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:text="Name" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/adapter_header_textview_column3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:textColor="@color/defaultTextColor"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="28sp" 
    android:text="Date"/>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/header_check_box"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:color="@color/defaultTextColor"
    android:layout_weight=".5"
    android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:background="@color/BPGreenColor" /> 
<ListView
 android:id="@android:id/list"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Then this is the array adapter I am using:

```
public class FastAssesmentListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Data> {

    private static int LAYOUT_ID = R.layout.list_adapter_with_checkbox_three_column;
private final Data[] assesments;
private final Context context;
LinearLayout listHeader;

static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView column1;
    protected TextView column2;
    protected TextView column3;
    protected CheckBox checkbox;
}

public FastAssesmentListAdapter(Context context, Data[] assesments) {
    super(context, LAYOUT_ID, assesments);
    this.context = context;
    this.assesments = assesments;
}

//ListFragment and array adapter will automatically call this over and over to auto populate the list
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Data item = getItem(position);

    // Formulate row view (create if it does not exist yet)
    View view = convertView;
    if(view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT_ID, null);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.column1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.adapter_textview_column1);
        viewHolder.column2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.adapter_textview_column2);
        viewHolder.column3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.adapter_textview_column3);
        viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check_box);
        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Clicked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), FacilityActivity.class);
                getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
            if(viewHolder.checkbox != null) {
                viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                      if(isChecked) {
                          item.setSelected(isChecked);
                          Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Checked",
                                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }

                    }
                  });
            }
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(position);
    }
    ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(position);
    viewHolder.column1.setText(item.getColumn1());
    viewHolder.column2.setText(item.getColumn2());
    viewHolder.column3.setText(item.getColumn3());
    viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(item.isSelected());
return view;
}
 }
```

on a side note, the onlistitemclicked in the fragment doesnt work, i have to set a listener in the adapter and then it works. any ideas on that? but mainly I need to figure out how to use a custom header and custom rows in the list view.  Here is the layout for the rows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="25dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"> 

<TextView android:id="@+id/adapter_textview_column1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/adapter_textview_column2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/adapter_textview_column3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/check_box"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".5"
    android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do I need to make a custom adapter for my header?

Comment: ok so I tried making a separate adapter for the header but then i cant add the adapter to the list fragment...